# Screen flickering / blinking / display on off in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, display, intel-graphics

Screen is blinking / flickering / constantly display one and off, when system resumes from suspend mode, It is not ending, I need to switch off and switch on again.

I am using Ubuntu MATE with following configuration:

[image: screenshot showing system information]

> ## ravikiran-Vostro-15-3538
>
> ### Ubuntu
>
> Release 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit
> Kernel Linux 5.4.0-40-generic
> x86_64   MATE 1.24.0
>
> #### Hardware
>
> Memory: 7.6 GiB
> Processor: Intel Core i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz x 4
> Graphics: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)

Answer (score 0):

Install Compiz

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-plugins compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Enable marco compositing manager in mate

```
dconf write /org/mate/marco/general/compositing-manager true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, this answer didn't solve my problem, same issue persists